# Interesting recursive behaviour with \frac error

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, fractions, recursion

I have this code below. Obviously it's not actually valid code because there's no second argument to `\frac`, but nonetheless I'm curious why it produces what it does.

```
\[
  \text{abc$\frac{123}$}
\]
```

[image]

You only see the recursive behaviour (getting the repeated, smaller abc-123) if you have the inline or display math mode, inside the `\text{}` command, inside an inline or display math mode. Changing which math mode you're using changes the result slightly, but the repated abc-123 is still there.

If you don't include the `\text{}` command, then you get the "expected" output, e.g.

`abc$\frac{123}$`
and
`\[ abc\frac{123} \]`
both give you the single abc-123

[image]

Does anybody have any clues on what inner workings gives the recursive behaviour?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\[
    \text{abc$\frac{123}$}
\]

\[
    abc\frac{123}
\]

abc$\frac{123}$

\[
    \text{abc\[\frac{123}\]}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text` uses `\mathchoice` internally.

Comment: … continued from Henri’s comment… so in a sense the “incomplete” `\frac` got typeset four times

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To understand what is going on, let us consider an example that is a bit simpler.  Define `\macro` to be a macro taking one argument

```
\newcommand\macro[1]{abc}
```

The argument is ignored and the expansion only contains `abc`.  Now let's use `\macro` in `\text` but omit the argument.

```
\[ \text{$\macro$} \]
```

The result is similar to what you observed:

[image]

To further understand this let us write out something that is similar to what `\text` does under the hood (radically simplified of course).  The output is the same as with `\text`.

```
\[ \mathchoice{\hbox{$\displaystyle \macro$}}%
              {\hbox{$\textstyle \macro$}}%
              {\hbox{$\scriptstyle \macro$}}%
              {\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle \macro$}} \]
```

Here we used `\mathchoice` which is a primitive which takes four arguments, one for every possible math style, indicated by the style macros that I'm using inside the `\hbox`.  Each argument is expanded and typeset in a temporary box but only the one corresponding to the current style is going to be output.  So the following snippet would result in

```
\[ \mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{SS} \] % -> D
$ \mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{SS} $ % -> T
$ _{\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{SS}} $ % -> S
$ _{_{\mathchoice{D}{T}{S}{SS}}} $ % -> SS
```

This is the mechanism that makes `\text` adapt correctly to the surrounding math style.  Now what happens in our example of the missing argument.  If we expand `\macro` we get

```
\[ \mathchoice{\hbox{$\displaystyle abc}}%
              {\hbox{$\textstyle abc}}%
              {\hbox{$\scriptstyle abc}}%
              {\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle abc}} \]
```

Oops, `\macro` ate the closing `$` and now there are lots of mismatched `$`.  We can now follow TeX as it is scanning along by reading the error messages.  The first error is

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.4 \[ \mathchoice{\hbox{$\displaystyle \macro$}
                                               }%
```

TeX tells us that the error occurred when reading the `}` after `\macro$`, indicated by the linebreak.  It also tells us that it was expecting a `$` but instead encountered a `}`.  Fair enough, since `\macro` just swallowed the `$`.  The exact same happens in the following lines and TeX is still looking for that closing `$` that never comes, so everything is being recorded in the first argument to `\mathchoice`.  This even extends beyond the math environment and only ends once the `$` are balanced or the end of the document is reached.  Eventually TeX realizes that things have been going wrong and it starts inserting multiple `$` and `}` until it is satisfied.  Then it typesets the first argument of `\mathchoice` which contains everything up until the invalid part.  You can produce fun stuff with this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\macro[1]{abc}
\begin{document}

$ \mathchoice{unused}%
             {\hbox{\color{red}$\textstyle \macro$}}%
             {scriptstyle}%
             {scriptscriptstyle} $
Wait, what is happing?
Why is everything red and in one line?
What happened to the linebreaks?
When is this ever going to end?

\end{document}
```

With `\frac` the situation is a bit more difficult to explain because it has a group inside of it but the rough working principle is the same.  The unterminated macro eats the trailing `$` and TeX keeps on scanning until the `$` are balanced or the end of the document is reached.

Comment: Why TeX *decides* to add closing math symbols instead of throwing an error? P.S. Very interesting answer!!

Comment: @manooooh As pointed out by egreg, TeX does throw errors: the 'recovery' goes back to the days that a run took ages, so was worth it; today, you are best stopping and fixing your input at the first sign of an error

Comment: Thanks! This was really interesting to read, and now I know that \mathchoice exists!

Answer (score 14):

The premise is wrong. There *is* a second argument to `\frac` in your code, which is precisely `$`.

The definition of `frac` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\@@over#2}}
```

where `\@@over` is the same as the primitive `\over` that `amsmath` redefines to yield a warning. Since the command wants two arguments, it can scan `{123}` as the first one and then, since no `{` follows, it absorbs the next *token* as the second argument. Thus you get the same as

```
$\frac{123}{$}
```

Now this is transformed into

```
${\begingroup123\endgroup\@@over$}
```

and this already will produce

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.6 $\frac{123}$

?
! Too many }'s.
\frac  #1#2->{\begingroup #1\endgroup \@@over #2}

l.6 $\frac{123}$

?
```

even if not inside `\text`. The `$` token is seen where it should not be, because of the yet unbalanced `{`, so TeX adds `}` for recovering; then it rescans `$`, which ends math mode and the next `}` triggers an error because it is no longer balanced by a corresponding `{`.

Within `\text` the situation is even worse, because `\text` will produce four versions of its argument in order to use just one of them according to the math style it ends up in. The two errors above will become *eight* error messages, but slightly different, because they're produced when TeX is in the middle of working on `\text` (`\text@` is its internal version, just for information):

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\text@ ...style \ssf@size {\firstchoice@false #1}}
                                                  \check@mathfonts }
l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\text@ ...firstchoice@false #1}}\check@mathfonts }

l.6 \[\text{$\frac{123}$}
                         \]
?
```

The three variations of “abc” followed by a denominatorless fraction result just as a byproduct of the error recovery and they shouldn't be taken “seriously”. It's actually quite surprising that hitting return eight times gets TeX in sync.